# Centering my logo over the custom header and right aligning my nav

Tags: html, css, centering

If you are viewing it on JSFiddle you'll have to make the results window bigger to see what I am talking about. The logo should be right over top of the half circle and header and the nav should be centered in the header and right aligned.

Here is the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/sPEXp/1/

HTML

```
    <div class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <a href="#"><img class="logo" src="img/onewaylogo.png"></a>
            <nav>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
                <a href="#">About</a>
                <a href="#">Let's Partner</a>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #f6f6f6;
    z-index: 10000;
    height: 100px;
}

.header .container {
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    width: 85%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.header:after {
    content: '';
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #f6f6f6;
    width: 150px;
    height: 75px;
    border-radius: 0 0 75px 75px;
}

.header .logo,
.header nav a {
    line-height: 100px;
}

.header nav {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    width: 320px;
}


.logo {
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 100000;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.header nav a {
    color: #aaa;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin: 0 0 0 20px;
    font-size: .95em;
}

.header nav a:hover {
    color: #333;
}
```

Comment: Why do you use position relative?

Comment: Not too sure.. I've been playing around with values and this is where I ended up. I tried removing all the position relative and that didn't help at all.. why, do you know the solution? :)

Comment: take a look at this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Memolition/dwL9r/2/embedded/result/)

Comment: I tried the obvious of making the logo absolute and then margin-right: 50% and margin:left: 50%, except that doesn't quite center it for some reason..

Comment: why is the left -75px value necessary, I know that works, so thank you for that, but it seems something else is off?

Comment: to center something you can try `position:absolute; width:100px; margin-left 50%; left: -50px;`

Comment: the `-75px;` value is to center, is the half of the total width

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34774/discussion-between-steveai-and-memolition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Fiddle Working](http://jsfiddle.net/Memolition/dwL9r/2/embedded/result/)

You can center elements by setting its width and position to  `absolute`
In this case:

```
.logo {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 50%;
    width: 150px;
    left: -75px; // total width half  (75px)
    ...
}
```